# Turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server

Tags: c#, wcf

Yo tengo una aplicación que cada 2 min llama a un método de un WCF service pero al parecer hubo problemas de conexión en los dos primeros intentos devolvió lo siguiente:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   https://xxxx.xxx.xx/Service.svc. This could be due to the service
>   endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due
>   to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due
>   to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Luego de esos dos intentos devolvió lo siguiente:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal
>   error.  For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.

Busque en google y explican que tengo que activar el IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults pero no termino de entender como hacerlo y esa es mi duda.

Les dejo el app.config de la aplicacion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="OfflineService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="Service.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="OfflineService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>



    <applicationSettings>
        <OfflineService.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Time" serializeAs="String">
                <value>120000</value>
            </setting>
        </OfflineService.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                  <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                  </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://xxxx.xxx.xx/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <userSettings>
        <OfflineService.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Folder" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\\log\\</value>
            </setting>
        </OfflineService.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315633/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-either-from-servicebehaviorattribute-or) de SOen

Comment: Lo vi pero no se que Service name ponerle, por lo que vi en google a la hora de definir el endpoint se le agrega una etiqueta service y se le asigna un nombre pero yo no lo tengo asi, no se donde tendria que ponerlo.